# Getting number format exception error in jmeter

Tags: function, jmeter

I am trying to generate `positive/negative decimal randomly with 8 digits` using jmeter `random` function. But getting exception.

My function : `${__Random(-99.99999999,99.99999999,)}`

Error : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-99.99999999"`

Note : I am passing above in json request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) returns a random [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) number within the given range, if you need Decimal - just call __Random() function twice: for part before the dot and for part after the dot, something like:

```
${__Random(-99,99,)}.${__Random(11111111,99999999,)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Random Function Demo]

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) to learn more about JMeter functions and get familiarized with the use cases.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was waiting for your answer as I was sure you will answer :)